# How do multimeters measure capacitance of polarized capacitors?

Tags: capacitance, multimeter

On my multimeter it doesnt matter in which polarity I put polarized capacitor.

How is it made?

If it is just simple rc circuit that measures charging time, how does it not damage capacitor in reverse voltage?

Comment: Why do you think that it doesn't matter? What do the instructions say? Do you have a model # for the meter?

Comment: Its FK64L. I do think so because there is no mark for negative or positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below a certain voltage (typically half a volt or more, depending) there is no problem in applying a negative voltage to polarized capacitors.

They can withstand negative voltage with similar mechanisms (oxide strength) as positive voltage, just the capability to withstand voltage is less because the relevant oxide layer is thinner.